# Angular not rendering value from app.component in HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How are you doing?

I'm trying to render a value acquired from http in app.component.ts to the HTML but it isn't working.
The value appears on console.log as a string but when I try to use it with `this.date = dateObj` it returns undefined.

When I access it from inside **parseString()** it doesn't work, but before it, it works. See on example for **date = 'today'**.

The HTML renders **'today'** but not the value of **dateObj**. The value of **dateObj** is a string, just to remember.

**HTML**

```
<h2>{{date}}</h2>
<input type="submit" value="test" (click)="onClickMe()"/>
```

**APP.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';


@Component({
    '...'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'testing';
  date: string;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void{}


    onClickMe(){

      ** removed for brevity. HTTP REQUEST code **

      //retrieve http to data
      this.http.post(url, body, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml') 
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS') 
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method")
  , responseType:'text'}).subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the response in XML and transform to JSON.
           var parser = new DOMParser();
           var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
           //today appears in HTML
            this.date = 'today';

          parseString(data, function (err, result) {
           var stringified = JSON.stringify(result);
           console.log(stringified);
           let jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringified);
           let dateObj = jsonObject['date'];

           //dateObj works fine on console.log but doesn't appear in HTML when rendering with {{date}}
            this.date = dateObj;


          });

    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
      }
    );

  }




}
```

The question is, there is a way to do that? How should I do it so I could render the value in HTML?

Comment: Post output of console.log(jsonObject);

Comment: A good programming **style** dictates that opening and closing brackets should be on the same _indentation_ level and overall your code is messy looking and a bit hard to read.(_Mixed indentation, lot of code in single line_  ) Please take time of prettying up your code before asking on SO. **It will be appreciated :)**

Comment: @Satendra the output is `{Dates: {…}}`

Comment: @EinārsBistrovs **I appreciate the tip!**

Answer (score 4):

assign it as `this.date = dateObj;` instead of `date = dateObj;`.

If that didn't fix, trigger a change detection by injecting the `ChangeDetectorRef` through constructor and calling the `detectChanges()` method.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

// call detectChanges() after this.date = dateObj;
this.date = dateObj;
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've got a `Cannot set property 'date' of undefined`.

Comment: Could you please show the relevant component methods in full?

Comment: `core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'date' of undefined
    at eval (app.component.ts:113)
    at Parser.eval (parser.js:303)
    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:81)
    at SAXParser.eval [as onclosetag] (parser.js:261)
    at emit (sax.js:624)
    at emitNode (sax.js:629)
    at closeTag (sax.js:889)
    at SAXParser.write (sax.js:1436)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (parser.js:322)
    at Parser.eval [as parseString] (parser.js:5)`

Comment: `(app.component.ts:113)` is for `this.date = dateObj;`

Comment: But are you calling the `parseString()` method you have defined anywhere in the code? Still not clear what you have in the component and how the particular method gets called. All you have there is just the definition of `parseString()` but I can't see how you are calling it

Comment: Yes I'm calling it right after `this.date = 'today';`

Comment: ParseString, once run, has it's own (this).  If you used an arrow function, it would maintain the same scope as the code around it.  You could keep the parse string method and call it as `parseString.call(this, [your arguments])` . However I recommend keeping with the newer pattern of arrow functions, OR making parse string a method on your class, instead of a free-standing function

Comment: Actually, turn the function you're passing to parseString into an arrow function...`function(err, result) {...}` should be `(err, result) => {...}`